# Python - downloading files from ftp based on the filename - very slow and crashes

Tags: python, ftp

The goal is to download specific files from an FTP server. Files have a date in their name and I want to download them based on those dates (specifically for this example - the year), so the file name is for example: 
stnobsKRNO_2007-01-01.csv and the only part that changes is the year.

I'm new to Python, so I have this so far:

```
# defining the local directory where we want to store the data 
dir_data = os.path.join(dir_work, 'data_renoobs')

yy = 1985

for yy in range (1985, 2018, 1):

    file_name = 'stnobsKRNO'+str(yy)+'-01-01.csv'

    # creating full local file name path
    file_name_full_path_local = os.path.join(dir_data, file_name)

    # creating the url for download
    url_base = 'ftp://ftp.server'
    url_full_path = url_base+file_name

    # download
    ret = urllib.request.urlopen(url_full_path) 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_full_path, filename=file_name_full_path_local)
```

The code seems to be functional, however it is very slow (small files, but it takes a while to download each of them...Plus it always crashes at some point and returns:

> URLError: urlopen error ftp error: EOFError()

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason to believe that the *"slow"* and *"crashes"* issues are related, you should ask them separately. + For the *"slow"* part, you have to also first prove that the server is capable is higher speeds (by comparing the results to speed of some standalone single-threaded FTP client). Otherwise it's not a programming question.

Comment: So the question was about the error, what may be causing it. As far as the speed I am only comparing it to using a "normal" FTP client, when downloading those files takes 1-2 seconds total as opposed to 1-2 seconds per file through python.